# reg ex right to left

Tags: regex

Putting this string

```
THX1138: The Movie
```

through this regular expression

```
(.)(.)(\d)(\d+)
```

matches this

```
HX1138
```

By leaving out the T from the match, it seems to be moving from right to left, but I thought the default was from left to right. For example, there are SO questions by people asking how to make the regex move from right to left, so I thought the default is left to right.  By adding another (.)

```
(.)(.)(.)(\d)(\d+)
```

It matches

```
THX1138
```

confirming the right to left observation. So is it some rule that if there are multiple capture groups, it moves from right to left after the first capture?

Comment: It's not moving from right to left. It's just looking for your pattern *as a whole* throughout the input, that is, from left to right. If the match is not found at index 0 then it advances to `input.substr(1)` then to `input.substr(2)` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break them down

1. `(.)(.)(\d)(\d+)`

   `(.)`: Match any single character
   `(.)`: Match any single character
   `(\d)`: Match any single digit
   `(\d+)`: Match one or more digits.

   Moving through your string `THX1138: The Movie`, left to right, the first three characters *cannot* match, because `X` is not a digit.  So it moves forward one character, and finds a match: `H` and `X` match the requirements for 'any single character', `1` matches 'any single digit', and '138' are slurped into the final `\d+`.
2. `(.)(.)(.)(\d)(\d+)`

   `(.)`: Match any single character
   `(.)`: Match any single character
   `(.)`: Match any single character
   `(\d)`: Match any single digit
   `(\d+)`: Match one or more digits.

   Now when it goes through your string, left to right, it finds a match immediately, because `T`, `H`, and `X` all match 'any single character', and once again, `1` matches 'any single digit', and `138` are slurped into the final `\d+`.

Comment: thanks perreal beat you by a minute so I accepted his answer but upvoted you too

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: I beat him by a minute... 49 > 48.  But whatever. heh

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, `THX1138` cannot match `..\d\d+` starting from `T` captured or not. Rather than failing the match, regex engine returns the only match for two whatever followed by at least two digits, aka, `HX1138`

Comment: flimzy beat you by a minute so I accepted his answer, but upvoted you